# How to loop through two directory paths in my find command

Tags: shell, unix

I'm trying to get all the files (**.csv** and **.log**) from 2 directories one from */web/local/artifacts/backup/csvs* and second one from */web/local/artifacts/home/archives* , basically looping both the directory paths in one `find` command.

I hardcoded the paths because I wanted to test it but its not looping through both the paths, currently its looping through the second path */archives* only.

Can you please help me with this issue?

```
find /web/local/artifacts/backup/csvs /web/local/artifacts/home/archives \
  -type f \
  -name "*.csv*" \
  -o \
  -name "*.log*" \
  -mtime +${LOG_RETENTION} \
  -exec ls -l {} \;
```

How can i loop through both the paths in this `find` command?

Comment: This code certainly does loop through both paths. You have a bigger problem, though, that you aren't defining your grouping. If I were to guess -- does one of the two directories only contain `*.csv` files, and the other one contain `*.log` files?

Comment: I suspect you _want_ `find path1 path2 '(' '(' -type f -name '*.csv' ')' -o '(' -name '*.log' -mtime +"$LOG_RETENTION" ')' ')' -exec ls -l {} +` -- notice how in that example we have the parens setting up _both_ branches of the `-o` to run the `-exec`. You don't strictly need quite that many, but it's better to be more explicit than less.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't related to the multiple paths you're passing; instead, it's because of how you're only putting `-exec` on one side of the `-o`, so it doesn't run for things found by the other side. Use parenthesis to define precedence to make it clear that the `-exec` applies to  all the other predicates:

```
find /web/local/artifacts/backup/csvs /web/local/artifacts/home/archives \
  '(' \
    -type f \
    -name "*.csv*" \
    -o \
    -name "*.log*" \
    -mtime +${LOG_RETENTION} \
  ')' -exec ls -l {} +
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, removed single quote after bracket ,  '('-type   didnt work but '(type worked.                                                                                                                                   find /web/local/artifacts/backup/csvs /web/local/artifacts/home/archives \
  '('\
    -type f \
    -name "*.csv*" \
    -o \
    -name "*.log*" \
    -mtime +${LOG_RETENTION} \
  )' -exec ls -l {} +

Comment: `'('` and `\(` are two ways of writing the exact same thing -- `find` literally can't tell which of the two formats were used, because the shell forms the same argument vector from either of them. I suspect maybe you left out a quote and thus made them unpaired? I strongly prefer `'('` because it's less ambiguous -- when code is embedded in strings, particularly in non-shell languages, it often happens that those strings get parsed in a way that eats backslashes.

Comment: if i remove quotes, im not getting the output properly, im getting all the files present in that directory, whereas if i put '('type f -name "*.csv*" -o -name "*.log*" -mtime +60')'  -exec ls -l {} \;  it says invalid argument -exec to mtime

Comment: Please don't use comments to paste multi-line code -- whitespace is important, and I don't know what your real whitespace is from the way the comment comes out (the code in your comment is missing spaces that aren't optional, but I can't tell if that's because you left them out altogether, or if it's just comment-based munging).

Comment: @VinodRavi, ...consider using https://gist.github.com/ or a similar ad-free pastebin to provide code in a form that doesn't get munged before I can see it. You might also consider an online sandbox like https://replit.com/languages/bash, https://ideone.com/ in bash mode, etc

Comment: @VinodRavi, ...note that `'('-type f` is not valid syntax -- you need space before and after the paren so it's parsed into a separate argument from `-type`, so it needs to be `'(' -type f` **with the space**. Same for the `)`, which needs to be a separate argument from `+60`, and also from `-exec`.